# how to add second onclick action from php

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, escaping

I have this line in php code:

```
$return .= '            <div class="acrDivP" onClick="javascript: window.location.href = \'' . $productUrl . '\';" id="acrLink">' . $resultText . '</div>';
```

I want to add a second onClick action as shown in bold (**) below:

```
$return .= '            <div class="acrDivP" onClick="javascript: window.location.href = \'' . $productUrl . '\';**ga('send', 'event', 'testEvent', 'click', 'ProductName');**" id="acrLink">' . $resultText . '</div>';
```

I know my syntax is horribly wrong since some charatcters have to be escaped. Could someone please help me fix the syntax? Or do I need a whole new approach?

Comment: Why not just make a function that does both of these things? It'd be cleaner.

Comment: Hi, Seiyria, I know this is the right thing to do but I wanted a quick solution before I make the next iteration. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$return .= '            <div class="acrDivP" onClick="javascript: ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'testEvent\', \'click\', \'ProductName\'); window.location.href = \'' . $productUrl . '\';" id="acrLink">' . $resultText . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it this way, it's just going to require a lot of gnarly escaping. This reduces both the readability and the maintainability of your code.

```
$return .= '<div class="acrDivP" onClick="window.location.href = \'' . $productUrl . '\'; ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'testEvent\', \'click\', \'ProductName\');" id="acrLink">' . $resultText . '</div>';
```

It would require some refactoring, but if you can break out of PHP for the code, it can be much cleaner:

```
<div class="acrDivP" onClick="window.location.href = '<?php echo $productUrl ?>'; ga('send', 'event', 'testEvent', 'click', 'ProductName');" id="acrLink"><?php echo $resultText ?></div>
```